# Knockout JS: Validation of Dropdowns inside the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Using Knockout JS here.

Current setup:

I have a HTML table and the table has 5 columns. I have button to add a row to table and then remove button against each row to delete it. I also have a dropdowns in 2 columns of this table. The first dropdown is populated from the button click event outside the table. Ie when you press get data button it populates the dropdown. Further when you select any dropdpwns the row data is adjusted with the selection.
Lastly there is a save button. When clicked I want to save all the data.

My dropdown is as below:

```
  <td><select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $parent.ddl, optionsText: 'firstName', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: '--Select--'"> </select></td>

  <td>
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedSeparator">
       <option value="">--Select--</option>
       <option value="#">#</option>
       <option value="@">@</option>          
     </select>
  </td>
```

Issue:

My question is regarding validation. Since I add each row on client side click which adds these dropdowns on the fly how can I have validations on the dropdowns
such that when the user clicks on Save button and if any row has dropdown not selected it highlights that row and throws error.

I have my jsfiddle setup as below:

https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/7wqvr854/2/

------Updated----------

I have now updated my jsfiddle. Now each dropdown has a different Id. See updated fiddle at:

https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/7wqvr854/51/

The HTML is now as below:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $parent.ddl, optionsText: 'firstName', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: '--Select--',  attr: { name: 'Items[' + $index() + '].Name', id: 'Items[' + $index() + '].Name'}" name="Items[0].Name" id="Items[0].Name"><option value="">--Select--</option><option value="">Alex</option><option value="">Sam</option> </select>
```

Where you can see ID and Name as: "Items[0].Name"
I have also added ID to my TD as tdName

Now on button click when I use the following code:

```
  var selectList = $('#tdName > select');
        for (var selectName of selectList) {
          //Here I can see my dropdown but how to check dropdown selected text/value here
        }
```

Would it be possible by above code I can loop though all dropdowns and see if selected or not

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSS class based on a condition to mark invalid rows.

HTML:

```
<tr data-bind="css: { invalidRow: isInvalid }">
```

CSS:

```
.invalidRow {
  background-color: #ffb8b5;
}
```

Javascript:

```
self.Save = function(){
    for (i in self.items()) {
    if (typeof self.items()[i].selectedValue() == "undefined") {
      self.items()[i].isInvalid(true);
      alert("Select all dropdown")
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I have updated my jsfiddle with your changes:  https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/7wqvr854/41/  . What else needs to change here to get it working

Comment: `isInvalid` should be on the item

Comment: Sorry thomas I am not clear. Would you be able to update the fiddle above for the required changes.

Comment: Thanks Thomas that works if you add a row and don't select anything in the first drop-down. However if you select first drop-down and don't select second one it passes validation.  How can we validate both . Also if you provide any inputs to my updated code in my post where I loop through the drop-down list. Thanks again for looking into

Comment: Thanks tomas I have adjusted my code with your changes and have made it working for both dropdowns. Thanks for the help.